# Promises: roll dice async

Tags: javascript

I was trying to transform this code:

```
function rollDie() {
  var random = prngInt()
  var dieVal = (random % 6) + 1
  var reroll = random > 251

  if (reroll) {
    return rollDie()
  } else {
    return dieVal
  }
}
```

Into async function using promises. The problem comes when I try to adapt this if else statement but I'm new to JavaScript and async programming.
I've started doing this (Promise function that I will use):

```
function getPseudoRandomInt() {
    function promiseBehaviour(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(prngInt()), 1000)
    }
    return new Promise(promiseBehaviour);
}
```

After that, I've tried to translate/adapt directly but isn't working.

My try:

```
function rollDieAsync() {
  var random = getPseudoRandomInt()
  var dieVal = random.then(x => (x % 6) + 1)
  var reroll = random.then(x => x) > 251

  if (reroll) {
    return rollDieAsync()
  } else {
    return dieVal
  }
}
}
```

This function is working but not the way I want, because if statement will not execute, since re-roll promise won't get evaluated.

I would like some help to do it but in the simplest way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like this:

```js
function rollDieAsync() {
  return getPseudoRandomInt()
    .then(random => {
      var dieVal = (random % 6) + 1
      var reroll = random > 251
      if(reroll){
        return rollDieAsync()
      }else{
        return dieVal
      }
   })
}
```

Comment: Thx I got it now.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use async/await syntax:

```js
async function rollDie() {
  var random = await getPseudoRandomInt();
  var dieVal = random % 6 + 1;
  var reroll = random > 251;

  if (reroll) {
    return await rollDie();
  } else {
    return dieVal;
  }
}
```

The async method rollDieAsync is actually a Promise. You can then use it like this:

```js
rollDieAsync().then((value)=>{ console.log(value)}
```